# C# Parsing specific xml

Tags: c#, xml

I wonder how do I parse a specific person by the id in the xml below?

Also lets say I wanna loop through them all and add them to a listview, How do I do that with XmlDocument?

```
<users>
  <user id="Marcus">
    <website>www.google.com</website>
    <type>1</type>
  </user>
  <user id="John">
    <website>www.youtube.com</website>
    <type>1</type>
  </user>
  <user id="Josh">
    <website>www.google.com</website>
    <type>2</type>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: I would recommend XElement/XNode/XLinq (or whatever it is called). I find it easier than XmlDocument. In any case, this is well documented/tutorial'ed...

Comment: What API do you intend to use - XDocument, XmlDocument, XmlReader, XmlPathNavigator ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a linq to xml example -

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"...");
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("/users/user[@id='John']");
var website = element.XPathSelectElement("website").Value;
var type = int.Parse(element.XPathSelectElement("type").Value);
```

Comment: Make sure to annotate the appropriate `using`s.

Comment: Worked after some modifications